# PHP - MySQL - Display specific data after insert

Tags: php, mysql

Dearest genius coders,

I have a form in which users create a Team from a number of selections.  These selections are created from a drop down menu that pulls from a MySQL DB.

```
<select name="A1">  
    <?php 
        $queryA1 = "select p_Num, p_Name from players where p_Class = 'A'";
        $resultA1 = mysql_query($queryA1);
        while ($lineA1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultA1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $lineA1['p_Num'];?>"> <?php echo $lineA1['p_Name'];?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

This displays as shown. The player name (p_Name) in the list, but the INSERT takes the player number (p_Num).

[image]

From there, I have an insert created that takes the players and puts them in a Team database, but uses the p_Num (player number / key) to reference in the Player database.

I'm not having issues with the insert, what I need is to display the results after submission to the user, but I want to display the player name (p_Name) not the player number (p_Num).

How would I go about this?

-Nick

Comment: So what is your question? You can simply do another select statement based on the p_Num if you already have it and then display it on the result set page. Are you currently displaying p_Num? If so, just switch it then.

Comment: When a Player is selected / submitted, say Bubba Watson, which as an ID (p_num) of "2" in the database, the "2" gets written to a field on the in the Teams table.  When submitted, I want to display "Bubba Watson" on the page instead of "2".

Comment: select p_Num, p_Name from players where p_Num = 2? You could use this on the next page since you get the ID already. Or even could do a join.

Comment: Ok, since I already have the p_Num which I can easily show with <?php echo $valA1;?>, can't I just use that value in a query?  say $query = "select p_Name from players where p_Num = $valA1";  ???